# How to create multiple instances of an application in cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, cloud, apache-zookeeper

i wanted to create a multiple instances of my application in either google cloud or EC2. I have two queries regarding this

1.How to achieve this?

1. Can we create a virtual instances by using zookeeper?

Comment: I love the list, that's made my day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google App Engine instances are started automatically, as your traffic raises. You may also have always on instances or backends instaces. Just read the docs: http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances.html

Google App Engine is not adequate to use with Zookeper. Since Java code runs in a [limited sandbox](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Sandbox), you may not be able to communicate with Zookeper at all. Also, you will have to start and end you backends programmatically, leading you to lots of work.

As for EC2, see this:
http://www.mail-archive.com/zookeeper-user@hadoop.apache.org/msg01083.html